# Append variable value from xml tags and put in xml file names using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having below XML as output and want to concatenate the value present in xml to xml file name dynamically. XML contains Single ID value and want to pass it in XML file name at run time using XSLT.

Output 1 XMl:

File name : Output.xml

```
<Accounts>

<customer>

<ID>1234</ID>

</customer>

</Accounts>
```

Output 2 XMl:

File name : Output.xml

```
<Accounts>

<customer>

<ID>4096</ID>

</customer>

</Accounts>
```

Expected Output file name : Output_1234.xml

```
<Accounts>

<customer>

<ID>1234</ID>

</customer>

</Accounts>
```

Expected File name : Output_4096.xml

```
<Accounts>

<customer>

<ID>4096</ID>

</customer>

</Accounts>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for achieve the desire output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

   <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:result-document href="{concat(substring-before(tokenize(base-uri(.),'/')[last()], '.xml'),'_', /Accounts/customer/ID,'.xml')}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="Accounts"/>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```